# What line of /proc/meminfo is the physical memory, available for applications

Tags: monitoring, memory

Ubuntu 10.4 Server x86.

I need to set up a monitor for the physical memory, available for user-space applications.

I.e. "Alert! Soon new allocations will force system to use swap".

But I'm confused by /proc/meminfo output. Which parameter should I monitor? I tried a couple of likely options, but looks like they do not corellate well with what I want. (Perhaps I just looked at a wrong data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the swapTotal/swapFree measures, as this will tell you when swap memory starts to get used. You may fine using free -m easier.